# How can I change gridview delete button name?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I change the text on the delete "button"? For example if I wanted to have "ban user" there.

[image: Delete buttons]

Comment: can you show the code you use to generate this grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `DeleteText` attribute to set the name of the command

```
<Columns>
   <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="Ban User"/>
```

If it's a `TemplateField` you can do it like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                         CommandName="Delete" Text="Ban User"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `markup` page

If it is a `CommandField, DeleteText="REMOVE"`

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ... DeleteText="REMOVE" />
```

If it is a `ButtonField, Text="REMOVE"`

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" ... Text="REMOVE" />
```